# Check status of process and restart process if unresponsive/stopped - Python

Tags: python, windows, process, windows-services, operating-system

I'm trying to build a small process monitoring script on Windows Server 2008.

The script would:

- find target process
- check status (running/unresponsive/stopped)
- kill and restart process if unresponsive/stopped

---

Any suggestion on the best way to implement this?

Comment: Did you look at pywin32? Anything?

Comment: How would you know if a process was unresponsive? Does Windows expose that information? Does Windows even _know_ that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming a process 'unresponsive' is quite subjective. It might be waiting for data and seem unresponsive, or it might be in a (endless) loop and seem unresponsive.

Usually, what people do is implement *hartbeat*. That is - have a very tiny socket server in the process where other processes can connect and send `ping` messages, to which it replies `pong`. What monitoring tools usually do is ping the process periodically, and if it doesn't respond within a timeout - it's considered unresponsive (and usually gets killed).

Comment: Hi Emil, I've implemented it this way! It is working great :)